# SQL-Azure Performance, Add Database or Add Server?

Tags: sql, database, performance, azure, azure-sql-database

This is not a traditional scale-up or scale-out question.

Please bear with me, here first allow me give an example:

I created a Sql Azure server and create a 1GB database inside, cost $9.99 a month.
(It has a master database as well, 1G, but Microsoft not charge us for that)

Ok, here is my question comes, when I need another 1G database for my application. Why I need another 1GB database? You may ask me this because the azure can support database up to 50GB. My answer is distribution, I know the data will reach 50G eventually, so I create the data model distribute and spread the data in different database.

For all the sake of **performance**, which option I should use:

1. Create another database in same server
2. Create another server and create a new database inside

Both option cost same.
I guess option 2 will be better, isn't it?

Comment: What are the expected usage patterns for the database?

Comment: write normal, read frequently. Small data in varchar. Little join, but lot of sorting. Basically, I save data in Azure Table Storage and save index in Sql Azure, balance cost and performance. Also easier for scaling.

Comment: If you are eventually going to have multiple 50GB databases I think Table Storage rather than SQL Server would be the way to go (and cheaper), if that's an option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure there are strong (or any) performance implications, my understanding is that the consideration is mostly a management one as some entities, mostly around security, are defined at server level and some at database level.

Behind the scenes the model is quite different anyway, and a multi-tenant one, so having separate SQL Azure server does not actually mean you get a dedicated server per-se. theoretically separate servers or separate databases may end up looking exactly the same.

Comment: I like to know (I cannot find anywhere from M$). For databases in same server, looks like in one IP, are in a same box or in a cloud of serves like what Table Storage like. If so, then both configuration are same, just make the database spread in cloud anyway. Ya, maybe they are same just like you said. I shouldn't ask this question in first place :)

Comment: SQL Azure Server is just logical separation of data. The performance you will get will be exactly the same whether you create 2 SQL Azure Servers with 1 DB or 1 SQL Azure Server with 2 DBs. Each SQL Azure DB lives for its own (if I may say so). As Yossi said, SQL Azure has quite different provisioning and management model. The performance would mostly depend on such things like SQL Azure trhotling, and how intense you are with the specific DataBase, rather then the "Server" in generl. I put "server" in quotes, because, as I said - SQL Azure Server is just logical entity, not a physical one.

Comment: Exactly, and to your question in the comment - the fact that the databases share IP is not an indication that they reside in the same server, just that you're talking to the same 'facade', which is of course needed for the DNS name to work. SQL Azure is a true platform as a service offering, and as such you should not worry about how it's actually deployed nor do you have any guarantees around that. 'it just works'.

Comment: As Yossi indicates, the only reason to choose separate servers is for different security policies or to geo-locate differently (which makes no sense to do in a sharding scenario). Behind the scenes there is a TDS load-balancer that forwards to a different physical server for each database (regardless of logical 'virtual' server created).  You are guaranteed to get a different server for each database servicing the request (i.e. Connection 1 to DB1 and Connection 2 to DB 2 will be different servers for sure).